# Zorin OS 6.3 installation hangs on "Preparing to Install"

Tags: system-installation, zorin

I'm looking for help on installing Zorin OS 6.3 32bit. The program gets stuck on the "preparing to install" phase.

[image: ss of error]

*original URL: [http://imgur.com/PulGPMD](https://imgur.com/PulGPMD)*

I've tried loading it in both "Live System", and "Graphics Safe Mode". Both get stuck at the same screen. Alternatively, I've tried the "Load the Installer Directly", right after startup, but I only receive an error. It's being run side by side a no longer working version of Windows 7 x32bit. When I try to boot from my hard drive "Drive Read Error Press Ctrl+alt+delete to re-reload" appears. Not sure if that's relevant, but figured it might be.

Answer (score 1):

This issue reported on the ZorinOS website sounds like your issue, titled: [Installation Hangs After Boot Menu](http://www.zoringroup.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2735).

The workaround reported in that post was to do the following:

> When you get to the boot menu in the live DVD, press the
>   <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key and then a command line will appear.

The type the following, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
nomodeset
```